# Remove attribute value from product

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

We have attributes with a default value, even if the attribute is not in the products attribute set, the default value for these products are shown in layered navigation.

Example
My keyboards category gets Mouse attributes shown in layered navigation with the default attribute value. So all my keyboards get "Right handed".

How can i remove the attribute value for these products ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
$catid = 'your cat. id';
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category->load($catid); 
$prodCollection = $category->getProductCollection();

foreach ($prodCollection as $product) {
    $prdIds[] = $product->getId(); ///Store all the product id in $prdIds array
}

foreach($prdIds as $product){

  $attributeCode = "your attribute code";
  $obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
  $_product = $obj->load($product);

  $_product->setData($attributeCode, "")
    ->getResource()
    ->saveAttribute($_product, $attributeCode); 

   echo $_product->getName() . ' is succesfully corrected' . '<BR>'; ;        
}
```

Please let me know if this helps you out.